# Create a SMILES from ASE Atoms

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment, smiles

I am trying to create a SMILES representation starting from a .xyz molecule description (positions + symbols) read as ASE Atoms.

How can I convert a given molecule as a SMILES string ?

Comment: Does it have to be using ASE only? If you have the .xyz file, a solution using [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/) is: `from rdkit import Chem`, `molecule = Chem.MolFromXYZFile('your_file.xyz')`, `smiles = Chem.MolToSmiles(molecule)`, `print(smiles)`

Answer (score 1):

In .xyz file there are only atom types and cartesian coordinates of a molecule, so it is generally not able to determine SMILES of that molecule unless you know all chemical bonds present in it.

However, there is a tool called [`xyz2mol`](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bkcs.10334) which helps this kind of task - it assigns possible chemical bonds with given .xyz file, and outputs molecule with topology.

To directly obtain SMILES, you can install the package as described in its [Github repo](https://github.com/jensengroup/xyz2mol) and invoke the script as:

```
xyz2mol.py your_molecule.xyz
```